# Delay a countdown clock until I change screens

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, clock, kivy-language

I am trying to make a simple memory game with a countdown at the beginning of every game. The app will begin with a begin memory test button that will take you to the first game. When the game screen comes on I want to begin the countdown from 10 seconds before it begins. Currently when I open the app the countdown begins before I change screens. The current game screen is called settings screen.

main.py

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        #get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def on_start(settings_screen):
        settings_screen.function_interval = Clock.schedule_interval(settings_screen.update_label, 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(settings_screen.stop_interval, 10)
    def stop_interval(settings_screen, *args):
        settings_screen.function_interval.cancel()
    def update_label(settings_screen, *args):
        settings_screen.root.ids.counter.text = str(int(settings_screen.root.ids.counter.text) - 1)

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include kv/homescreen.kv
#:include kv/settingsscreen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        SettingsScreen:
            name: "settings_screen"
            id: settings_screen
            Label:
                id: counter
                text:"10"
        GameScreen:
            name: "game_screen"
            id: game_screen
```

settingsscreen.kv

```
<SettingsScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#39B3F2")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        rows: 2
        ImageButton:
            source: "kv\\icons\\red1.png"
            on_release:
                print("selected red button")
        ImageButton:
            source: "kv\\icons\\yellow1.png"
            on_release:
                print("selected yellow button")
        ImageButton:
            source: "kv\\icons\\yellow2.png"
            on_release:
                print("selected yellow button")
        ImageButton:
            source: "kv\\icons\\red2.png"
            on_release:
                print("selected red button")
```

Comment: Try using the `on_enter` event of the [Screen class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen).